# Is there any possibilities to create an expiry for google map markers? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, database

I am using Google Maps API to allow users to create markers, which would then be submitted to my database. Is there any way to create a time limit for deleting the marker (e.g. 2 hours) after the user has initially submitted the marker?

Comment: When you add the marker to the database either add the expire time or the actual time it was added then when you pull out the data from the database to build the markers filter by the expire time or actual time - X hours. Something like that would work.

Comment: can you add a time stamp when submit to your database and use that? e.g. with a DELETE WHERE timestamp < 2 hours ago